# android.apk file not being generated in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tools-for-apache-cordova

After upgrading to VS 2017 15.6, when I build my Ionic 1.3 / Cordova project, in "Release" configuration I no longer get a file named `android.apk` in the bin\Release folder. Instead I am getting a file named `VSBuildInfo.xml`.

I used to use the `android.apk` to deploy to my device. How do I do that now?

Comment: I also got android certificate issues with Xamarin.Forms after 15.6 update, so I made a rollback to 15.5.7

Comment: I had to add a `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>` tag to the `.jsproj` file just to get it to build https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/209035/apache-cordova-tools-error-after-upgrading-to-vs-2.html

Comment: ok, post this as answer

Comment: It's not the answer. It builds now, but it doesn't generate an apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something has changed and it's now working as long as I select "Device" as the target.

I don't remember having to select "Device" as the target when building in previous versions and I was pretty sure that when I was building in "Release" configuration that I did have it selected as the target - but I could be wrong about that.

One thing I did do was connect a device and click "Deploy" instead of "Build". So it is possible that doing that triggered something that made it start working. This could be a red herring, because it is now working consistently.

If I select "Simulate..." instead of "Device" as the target, then I get a `VSBuildInfo.xml` file instead of an `apk`, as described in my question.